# Git и GitHub на windows от новичка

Tags: dvcs, windows, git, github

1. Обязательно ли надо иметь `repo` на GitHub.com (или другом подобном хостинге)? Над проектом работаю один на компьютере и нетбуке, поэтому GitHub мне не нужен. (Возможно спросите зачем мне тогда Git. Отвечаю: а)интересно б)нужно знать в этом мире хотя бы одну систему контроля версий в)для удобства)
2. Взаимодействие между всеми `repo` происходит одинаково? Например, есть ли разница между взаимодействием `repo` на одном компьютере с `repo` на другому компьютером и `repo` на компьютере с `repo` на GitHub?
3. GitHub предоставляет свою программу GitHub. Для чего это программа? Она обязательна для работы с `repo` на GitHub.com?. Я так понимаю, эта программа нужна, чтобы работать с `repo` на GitHub.com и для упрощения взаимодействия Git'а с `repo` на GitHub.com. Так?
4. Как лучше работать с Git: с GUI или через Bash или еще что-то? А как проще? Наверняка будут аргументы и за GUI и за Bash или еще что-то. Ведь не зря существуют разные варианты.
5. Допустим есть `repo` для своего проекта на GitHub. Создан проект в MS VisualStudio. Где должен находиться repo на компьютере? В папке с проектом? А какие обычно файлы попадают в repo? Все файлы? Только файлы кода? Файлы кода и ресурсы (картинки, видео и т.д.)? Или еще что-то?
6. Как проходит обычный процесс работы над проектом? Допустим, поработал над проектов в MS Visual Studio. Теперь надо зайти в Git (GUI или Bash) и там закоммитить все изменения. Так?
7. В Git Bash на windows не работает ни Ctrl+V, ни ПКМ+вставить. Непонятно как работать с редактором, который открывается после выполнения команды `git commit`. Как сохранить запись в этом редакторе? Если есть 2 или более коммита и если написать `git log -p -2`, то покажет только первый коммит, на втором остановится и надо что-то ввести, иначе ничего нельзя сделать. Откуда узнать что надо вводить? Это вообще все так и должно быть? Как с этим "бороться"? Есть ли нормальная альтернатива Git Bash?
8. Почему в заголовке Git Bash написано "MINGW32:~"?

Comment: 7. Чтобы вставить текст в консоли, нужно сначала настроить консоль. Нажмите ALT + SPACE, выберете пункт "свойства", дальше раздел "общие" и активируйте чекбокс "Выделение мышью". Теперь вы сможете вставлять текст из буфера обмена в консоль с помощью щелчка правой кнопки мыши, а чтобы копировать текст из консоли в буфер обмена, нужно выделить его и тоже нажать правую кнопку мыши.

Comment: А теперь насчет работы с редактором, вы можете изменить редактор по умолчанию на свой, введя команду `git config --global core.editor "'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Notepad++\\notepad++.exe' -multiInst -notabbar -nosession -noPlugin"`
8. Если хотите все как в линукс, то можете использовать Cygwin с установленными пакетами git, там будет все также как в линукс.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

1. Можно не иметь. Но лучше иметь, там ваш проект защищён, и никуда не денется. А пользоваться git-овым репозиторием локально для проекта, даже без удалённого репозитория — отличная идея.
2. Не совсем понятен вопрос. Попробуйте разобраться с тем, что такое локальный и удалённый (remote) репозитории, тогда вам будет более понятна разница между репозиторием из папки `.git` и github'ом (или любым другим git сервером).
3. Совсем не обязательно. Рекомендую изучить работу с командной строкой.
4. Что удобнее — каждый выбирает для себя сам. Но есть случаи, когда без командной строки не обойтись.
5. Локальный репозиторий находится в подпапке `.git` вашего проекта. В него попадают все файлы, которые вы туда добавите. Если какие-то файлы или папки не должны туда попадать, например, скомпилированные двоичные файлы, то их можно исключить, занеся их в файл `.gitignore`.
6. Так. Иногда даже лучше это делать чаще. Ведь предыдущий коммит можно дополнить. А вот испорченный код можно откатить только до состояния предыдущего коммита (когда <kbd>Ctrl+Z</kbd> уже не помогает). Изучите ветки — это так же просто, как копировать папку проекта целиком в папки вида `backup1`, но гораздо удобнее.
7. Попробуйте воспользоваться средней клавишей мыши для вставки, предварительно убедившись, что вы можете впечатывать туда с клавиатуры. Либо нажмите <kbd>Esc</kbd> и потом <kbd>P</kbd>. Редактор для коммитов предполагает, что вы знакомы с редактором Vim и его сочетаниями клавиш. Записать будет `ZZ`, добавить строку - `o`, перейти из режима ввода текста в командный - <kbd>Esc</kbd>, обратно - `a`, `i` или `o`. Если не умеете пользоваться редактором, пользуйтесь заданием сообщения для коммита через командную строку, вот так:

   ```
   git commit <file> -m 'здесь сообщение коммита'
   ```

> Если есть 2 или более коммита и если
>   написать git log -p -2, то покажет
>   только первый коммит, на втором
>   остановится и надо что-то ввести,
>   иначе ничего нельзя сделать.

Можно проматывать стрелочкой вниз или клавишами <kbd>J</kbd>/<kbd>K</kbd>, можно искать клавишей <kbd>/</kbd>.

> Есть ли нормальная альтернатива Git Bash?

bash тут в общем-то ни при чём. Основные команды редактора Vim знать полезно, они работают во многих стандартных утилитах (less, man и т.п).

Comment: Отличный ответ, практически слово в слово хотел ответить :)
Только я еще бы посоветовал бы книгу http://git-scm.com/book

Comment: @pustserg: Даже можно сразу на русский перевод. http://git-scm.com/book/ru

Comment: @pirj ну вопрос о выборе языка пусть лучше решает топикстартер, английский знать все равно крайне желательно :)

Comment: http://git-scm.com/book/ru читаю, но там чисто про Git вроде как.
2)Т.е. компьютер, за которым я работают - локальный, а repo остальных участников и repo на GitHub это удаленные repo? Если так, то вы хотите сказать, что разницы не будет что это за удаленный repo?
5)Т.е. это ответ "Да" на мой вопрос? Repo разве не находиться в папке на уровень выше, чем .git? По всем урокам и упражнениям в интернете рабочие файлы проекта находятся на уровнем выше. И как пишут, .git что-то типа служебной папки для Git и вообще она скрыта.

Comment: 7)Насчет вставки ничего не сработало. Где можно посмотреть описание редактора? Команды вставки и т.д. Редактор Git Bash и редактор коммита это разные вещи в плане работы с редактором? Или Git Bash это тот же Vim?

Еще вопрос появился.

8)Когда делается коммит, делаются слепки(snapshot) индексированных файлов. Что такое слепок? Это полная копия файла? Если да, то почему я не могу найти этой копии в repo?

Comment: 7) если не хочется разбираться с редактором, то используйте параметр m (`git commit -m "текст сообщения для коммита"`).

8) нет там копий файлов. Это было бы не логично. Там хранятся диффы.

А фраза "Когда делается коммит, делаются слепки(snapshot) индексированных файлов" значит то, что когда делается коммит (выполняется команда commit), то git не смотри на те файлы, которые находятся в каталоге пользователя, а смотри в индекс, куда пользователь добавил то, что он хочет закоммитить (а в индексе опять же не файлы хранятся, а снимки файлов. Это такая абстрация, что бы не думать, что же там).

Comment: Книга по гит? Это ведь просто сервис контроля версий? Чем он так велик что вокруг него такой шум? Я никак не пойму чем он столь особенный на фоне обычного сервера где все могут синхронизировать свои данные или тот же Дропбокс, Google Drive...