# Контроль версий на локальном компьютере windows

Tags: windows, git, контроль-версий

Достаточно давно пишу одну программу. Для сохранения всех данных использую бэкапы. Но вот решил использовать систему контроля версий. И так что я хочу от системы контроля версий:

1. Она должна работать на локальном компьютере и под Windows
2. Иметь как консольный так и GUI интерфейс
3. Интегрирована с Visual Studio

И тут возникают трудности: любая статья для чайников предлагает либо использовать гитхаб, либо ставить и настраивать прорву программного обеспечения (база данных, веб сервер...). А может кто подсказать (или кинуть в меня ссылкой) как просто и быстро настроить систему контроля версий (git предпочтительней) с сервером на локальном компьютере?

Comment: Если ставить студию 2013 или 2015, то она ещё при инсталляции спрашивает - "гит поставить?" Сразу решает кучу вопросов.
Если сильно хочется какую-то интеграцию в студию - попробуйте это http://gitextensions.github.io/

Answer (score 16, accepted):

## 1. Установка

Git не нуждается в сервере. Под Windows ставьте это: 
[gitforwindows.org](https://gitforwindows.org/). Там есть 32- и 64-битная версия.

Вместе с git будет установлена unix-подобная консоль git-bash и GUI-инструмент. 
В качестве ещё одного GUI вы сможете использовать Visual Studio.
Есть множество других GUI, но при умении работать через консоль и наличии полноценной IDE они вам не пригодятся.

#### 1.1. Интеграция с Visual Studio

Если нужна интеграция с Visual Studio, вы можете установить http://gitextensions.github.io/. В комплекте есть плагин для VS. (Ссылка из [комментария KoVadim](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/584813/%D0%9A%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C-%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B9-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BC-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BF%D1%8C%D1%8E%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5-windows/584819#comment781020_584813))

## 2. Запуск и первоначальная конфигурация:

Откройте командную оболочку git-bash: кликните правой кнопкой мыши на свободном месте в любой папке и выберите пункт <kbd>git bash here</kbd>.

Выполните базовую [конфигурацию](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Getting-Started-First-Time-Git-Setup#Your-Identity), это нужно сделать один раз. Используйте ваше имя и принадлежащий вам почтовый ящик. Если вы настраиваете Git на рабочем месте, скорее всего вам нужно использовать рабочую почту.

```
git config --global user.name "John Doe"
git config --global user.email johndoe@example.com
```

И чтобы использовать окончания строк CRLF, как принято в Windows:

```
git config --global core.autocrlf true
```

Вместо консольных команд можно редактировать файл конфига в любом текстовом редакторе (локальный расположен в `%папка_проекта%\.git\config`, глобальный в `C:\Users\%имя_юзера%\.gitconfig`).

## 3. Начало использования

Если git bash уже открыта, перейдите в папку проекта:

```
cd С:/путь/к/проекту
```

Или сразу кликните правой кнопкой мыши на свободном месте **в папке проекта** и выберите пункт <kbd>git bash here</kbd>.

Теперь, чтобы создать локальный репозиторий и таким образом начать контроль версий проекта:

```
git init
```

## Документация

Ещё по этой теме:

- [Git и GitHub на windows от новичка](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/174606/181472)
- [Git и GitHub на windows от новичка (часть 2)](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/181369/181472)
- [Как настроить autocrlf в git для различных систем?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/406466/181472)

Входная точка документации: https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2

Comment: Все-таки я бы рекомендовал поставить еще Git Extensions. Там очень удобно предварительно просматривать изменения - это снимает проблемы вида *"закоммитил в гит то, не знаю что, теперь лезут конфликты"*

Comment: @PavelMayorov если хотите, добавьте рекомендацию куда-нибудь рядом с абзацем про VS. Думаю, это будет вполне уместно.

Comment: Я так красиво, как вы, не сформулирую...

Comment: @PavelMayorov а почему вы рекомендуете Git Extensions? Оно чем-то превосходит разные другие GUI или это не только GUI?

Comment: Оно позволяет в одном окне видеть статус файлов, диффы, делать add, reset (как в режиме unstage так и hard) и commit. Кроме того, там можно работать с отдельными строками файла - куда удобнее чем через командную строку; этой возможностью я часто пользуюсь для .csproj-файлов.

Comment: Еще blame гораздо удобнее делать в git extensions.

Comment: @PavelMayorov согласен, blame из командной строки вообще неудобен. Мне нравится как в семействе IDEA это сделано — по клику открывается просмотр коммита, в котором изменилась строка. Можно посмотреть на контекст изменений. Кстати, в VS наверняка так же?

Comment: В VS доступна история на уровне методов - можно посмотреть список коммитов, изменявших конкретный метод, и авторов для них же. Выглядит вот так: https://i.stack.imgur.com/aYBT6.png. Тоже удобная фича, но вот конкретно blame в студии нет.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/62122/discussion-between-nick-volynkin-and-pavel-mayorov).

Answer (score 2):

Не самый каноничный вариант, но для любителей GUI очень даже неплохо - https://tortoisegit.org/ (есть на русском).

Все, что нужно для работы будет установлено локально, включая сам git. Есть gui, которым первое время можно будет пользоваться, а потом (по желанию) перейти на командную строку.

Быстрый старт:

- скачиваем/устанавливаем tortoisegit
- кликаем правой кнопкой по вашей папке, затем "Создать репозитарий здесь"
- и, когда нужно сохранить работу, правой кнопкой по папке и "Commit"

Пример просмотра лога коммитов:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Надо быть осторожнее с программами, которые интегрируются в Проводник. Они довольно сильно все замедляют.

Comment: @PavelMayorov это про бейджики, которые поверх иконок файлов рисуются? (замедление)

Comment: И они в том числе.