# bower and git проблема

Tags: html, git, sass, npm

Как устранить ошибку ? git установил в окне комманд

> ```
> D:\StyleDream>bower i OwlCarousel2
> bower ENOGIT        git is not installed or not in the PATH
> ```

Comment: должно быть установлено nodejs, gitbush + желательно поставить conemu командную строку и там запускать все!

Comment: @user3178479 под gitbush вы имели в виду git bash? А nodejs нужен для того, чтобы bower заработал?

Comment: @NickVolynkin, точно

Comment: Я бы рекомендовал очень удобный консольный эмулятор [cmder](http://cmder.net/), есть версия со встроенным гитом. Очень удобная вещь под винду, с оболочкой bash. Если интересно, есть удобный [мануал](https://isqua.ru/blog/2016/11/05/nastroika-tierminala-cmder-v-windows/) по его настройке (там несложно).

Answer (score 2):

Вам нужно установить `git` в систему -> **https://git-scm.com/downloads**.

Или если он у вас уже есть, например, вы ставили "портабельную" версию , пропишите в переменную PATH на своей машине, путь к папке и исполняемым файлом `git`.

1. Зайдите в панель управления
2. Выберите система
3. Нажмите дополнительные параметры системы
4. Нажмите переменные среды
5. И в системную переменную **Path** добавьте путь к паке с программой `git`:

   ```
   C:\Program Files (x86)\SmartGit\git\bin
   ```

Comment: @Aslero, как добавите в `Path` не забудьте новое окно консоли запустить, он считывается только на запуске.

Comment: Чтобы заработало форматирование кода внутри списка, нужно добавить ещё четыре пробела (всего восемь получается).

Answer (score 2):

Вы пытаетесь использовать git в cmd.exe, где он по умолчанию не настроен. Если вам привычно работать именно в cmd.exe и вы хорошо знаете его синтаксис, вы можете настроить `PATH`, как [описано в соседнем ответе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/599467/181472).

Но даже в таком случае, и тем более, если командная оболочка (консоль) для вас пока в новинку, я рекомендую использовать git bash. Это unix-подобная (вернее [POSIX](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/POSIX)-подобная) оболочка, которая входит в комплект поставки Git for windows. Аргументы за то, чтобы её выбрать:

1. Работает сразу после установки Git for windows.
2. Подавляющее большинство справочных материалов по Git (в частности, на Stack Overflow) написано с использованием POSIX-синтаксиса. Вы просто сэкономите время.
3. (субъективно) Фронтенд-разработчику в любом случае нужно осваивать этот синтаксис, т.к. обычно ваш сайт будет работать на unix-подобном сервере.

Инструкции по первоначальной конфигурации и запуску git bash есть в вопросе [Контроль версий на локальном компьютере windows](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/584819/181472).