# Как использовать git на Windows в Rubymine?

Tags: windows, git

На линуксе всё понятно, сгенерировал ssh ключ, соединил его с гитхабом и всё нормально.
А вот на винде в таком софте как rubymine как китом воспользоваться? 
После того как я пытаюсь пушить:

```
git push -u origin master
```

мне выдаёт

> Permission denied (publickey).

У меня есть приложение рельсовое. В нём уже гит установлен всё нормально.
Как слить через терминал теперь в репозиторий?
ssh-key команды не пашут.

Я так предполагаю мне надо как то наверное тоже сгенерировать ключ ssh или типо того и его в гитхабе вписать в профиле?

Comment: `ssh-key команды не пашут` – можно подробнее, как вы пытались сгенерировать ключ, какое сообщение об ошибке?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Чтобы работала авторизация по ключу (без пароля):

1. Если ещё не установили git для Windows – [установите](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/584819/181472).
2. Через git bash [сгенерируйте ключ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/468870/181472).
3. Добавьте публичную часть ключа в свою учётку на GitHub.

Если хотите открывать git bash из среды RubyMine, нужно её настроить ([инструкцию перевёл с enSO](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21676150/2790048)):

1. Меню File (Файл) → Settings (Настройки) → (Введите 'Terminal' в строку поиска).
2. В открывшемся окне настроек поменяйте значение `Shell path` на:

   ```
   "C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\sh.exe" --login -i
   ```

Answer (score 3):

Возможно вам стоит попробовать [Git for Windows](https://git-scm.com/download/win). Данный пакет помимо графической обочки, включает эмуляцию bash. При установке будет предложено три варианта:

- отдельная bash-консоль
- минимальный набор UNIX-команд для использования в командной строке Windows
- полноценное UNIX-окружение в командной строке Windows
  (меняется поведение ряда команд, таких как `find` и `sort`).

Home-директорией будет выступать ваш User-каталог, в котором можно создать подпапку .ssh и положить ваши ключи, как в UNIX-подобной операционной системе.

Если ключи не будут подцепляться из директории автоматически, можно поставить Windows-SSH-агент. Для работы с SSH в Windows есть набор [Windows-утилит](https://git-scm.com/download/win), включая всем хорошо известный PyTTY. В нем есть утилита `puttygen.exe`, которая позволяет либо сгенерировать новый ключ, либо преобразовать существующий UNIX-ключ. Этот ключ можно загрузить в агент `pageant.exe`, который будет висеть в трее и предоставлять ключ для SSH-операций, как `ssh-agent` в UNIX. Да, к сожалению, это приведет к тому, что в UNIX и Windows у вас будут разные закрытые ключи, однако за счет преобразования можно добиться того, что публичный ключ будет один и тот же.

Comment: А есть ли смысл на нескольких машинах использовать одни и те же ключи? Всегда ведь можно добавить несколько публичных.

Comment: Да, имеет, если работать приходится с несколькими хостами, к которым нет доступа и к которым доступ предоставляется администраторами (отдельными людьми, которые могут ошибаться, увольнятся и т.п.). Как только появляется два или более ключей - начинаются проблемы. А так один человек - один ключ, если доступ открыли к тачке, можно быть уверенным, что там именно тот ключ, который нужен (а не один из них). Если доступа нет - отлаживается все быстрее. Наверное это сильно зависит от условий работы, коллективов, взаимодействия в коллективах.

Comment: Вы забыли упомянуть @NickVolynkin.

Comment: @Arhad, Ник модератор и топ-отвечающий по git, я думаю он не пропустит ответ )

Comment: @cheops я из параноидальных соображений держу разные ключи на разных машинах. Уволился — отовсюду удалил ключи от рабочей машины, а от личного ноутбука они остались. Но ваша аргументация мне тоже понятна.

Comment: @cheops мы в команде практиковали такой способ: есть репозиторий, в нём лежит плейбук Ansible для накатывания пользователей с ключами. Там же в файле с переменными лежат все данные по каждому члену команды: имя, почта, публичные ключи. Когда нужно кому-то выдать доступ на какой-то хост, на этом хосте запускается плейбук, создаётся пользователь, добавляются ключи. Но у нас было весьма ограниченное количество хостов и тем более пользователей. Для той же техподдержки такая схема вообще не подойдёт.

Comment: Кстати, плюс за Putty. Хорошо, что объяснили про возможность конвертировать ключ.

Comment: @NickVolynkin на самом деле все зависит от администраторов и именно они диктуют политику. Я как разработчик, полностью от них завишу. Если служба эксплуатации говорит мне запаролить ключ - я его запаролю, если она говорит перемещать его только на флешках - я так и делаю. Скажет, что будет несколько ключей - возьму под козырек )